# Content not displaying inside trapezoid shaped div

Tags: html, css

so i have a trapezoid shaped div which is located on the left side of the page and is supposed to be the navigation bar, but for some reason the content of the (ul) is being displayed outside the trapezoid to the right. how can i make its contents display inside and not out?

HTML:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  border-left: 100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <nav>

    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</div>
```

its probably something quite obvious as im not that experienced in html. :P

Comment: is it because navbar width is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually being displayed outside because it has position absolute and the container's width is 0.

The black part you have achieved is a border, no content will go on the borders unless they are moved.

Applying `left:-100px;` will move the UL at the right place (100px being the width of the border).

Also note that it is futile to use `float` and `position:absolute` together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add `margin-left: -85px;` inside `margin-left: -85px;`

```css
 html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  border-left: 100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -85px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="navbar">
  <nav>

    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Products</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Salketer suggested, yes it is wrong to use float with position:absolute. 
Better use left or right with position:absolute.

```
navbar ul {
       color:#fff;
       list-style: none;
       position: absolute;
       padding-left: 0px;
       text-align: left;
       right: 0;
      }
```

Check [Here](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/VzdzRa)